# Unable to import requests - No module named `http.client`

Tags: python-3.x, http, ubuntu

Using python3 on Ubuntu Server 22.04.
Trying to import the requests library in a python script using `import requests`

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/mahmoud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.client'
```

I have tried to reinstall python3 through apt, and that didn't fix it.
I have tried using `pip`, but I can't even run `pip` because I get the same error.
I have tried rebooting my computer, and that also didn't fix it.